# Kubernetes Python client connection Issue

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-python-client

I have setup Official Kubernetes Python Client (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

I am running Python code to connect to a Kubernetes cluster and it's throwing an **error**:

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****', port=6443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

**Installed requirements:**

```
cachetools        3.1.0 ,
certifi           2019.3.9 ,
chardet           3.0.4 , 
google-auth       1.6.3 ,
idna              2.8 ,
ipaddress         1.0.22 ,
kubernetes        10.0.0-snapshot ,
oauthlib          3.0.1 ,
pip               19.0.3 ,
pyasn1            0.4.5 ,
pyasn1-modules    0.2.4 ,
python-dateutil   2.8.0 ,
PyYAML            5.1 ,
requests          2.21.0 ,
requests-oauthlib 1.2.0 ,
rsa               4.0 ,
setuptools        41.0.0 ,
six               1.12.0 ,
urllib3           1.24.1 ,
websocket-client  0.56.0 ,
wheel             0.33.1
```

`kubectl` is working fine with the same config `$HOME/.kube/config` and same proxy settings.

Below is my code:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried executing `kubectl` from the host the python is being executed?

Comment: @Crou,  yes, kubeclt works fine on the same host the python code is being execute.  The proxy setting same for both kubectl and python execution. I also tried kubernetes official golang client. It works fine.  I am facing issue only with python setup.  Is it problem with the python Version Iam using ?

Comment: Which version of the Python client and Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: @char  Kubernetes Version:  v1.11.8   -----------------------  Kubernetes-Python client version:  10.0.0   $pip show kubernetes   Name: kubernetes  Version: 10.0.0-snapshot  Summary: Kubernetes python client  
-----------------------

Comment: Maybe open an issue on the python client repo?

Answer (score 4):

In my case simply loading the config via `load_kube_config` didn't work as well. I ended up first running a proxy:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8888
```

and then changing the host using the `Configuration` object:

```
configuration = client.Configuration()
configuration.host = "localhost:8888"
api_client = client.CoreV1Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the host ID for your client. You can find this in [AI Platform Pipelines](https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/pipelines) >> Settings. The code will look similar to this:

```
import kfp
client = kfp.Client(host='###########-dot-us-east1.pipelines.googleusercontent.com')
```